# How to generate a database schema effectively

Tags: java

I am looking to create a lot of tables in a Java application. This would include creating tables,  reading from tables etc. Now I don't want to liter my code with alot of create, `select * from type code`. Is there any library that I could use to easily create the data tables, insert into them etc.

Answer (score 1):

[ORM (object relational mapping)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool is what you are exactly looking for, [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) is very mature and actively developed tool around it